# creating a dataframe by using a list - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a list of 270 listitems  and i would like to transfer to a dataframe.
I would like to divide the content of the list into three  dataframe columns containing 90 items per column. #

Col A    Col B     Col C

[0:89] [90:179]   [180:269]

of course i could use List slicing and so on for this case.
The problem is, that the number of items in the list is not fixed. It can vary.
There can be also list length of 360,450,540 and so on (always 90 more items).

Is there anybody who can give me a hint to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance
Best regards
Sascha

Comment: so how many columns would there be if you have 360 items, 4 columns?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could simply use `range` and slices:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({f'Col{i + 1}':
                  lst[i * 90: (i+1) * 90] for i in range(len(lst)//90)})
```

The good news is that this will silently ignore additional values if the length of the list is not an exact multiple of 90.

Comment: thank you. thats exactly what i was looking for .

Answer (score -2):

use this piece of code

```
import pandas as pd

col_1 = your_list[0:89] 
col_2 =  your_list[90:179]
col_3 =  your_list[180:269]  
my_dict = {
    'Col A': col_1,
    'Col B': col_2,
    'Col C': col_3
}

df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
```